# How to inject script with gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have installed 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-string

and create this gulpfile.js :

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// Include Our Plugins
var inject = require('gulp-inject-string');

gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(inject.before('</body>', '<script src="myscript.js"></script>\n'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./test'));
    console.log('myscript.js injected');
});
```

When executing gulp, console.log executed correctly but index.html has not been injected any script before /body tag.

What should I fix ?

Update : I tested to another folder, index.html is written but no script is injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you have injected you haven't written that to an output file.

You can try something like this

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(inject.before('</body>', '<script src="myscript.js"></script>\n'))
.pipe(rename('<Name of the file>'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('<output folder>'));
    console.log('myscript.js injected');
});
```

Comment: Thanks updated my script with .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));  .pipe(gulp.dest('./')); and but still does not work. I want to overwrite existing index.html

Comment: Try writing to a different folder

Comment: It writes to another folder but still doesn't inject any script

Comment: if you want to write to same folder you will have to rename file to a different name

Comment: OK let's write to another folder test still no script is injected

Comment: Its working for me i just did a simple poc. If you don't mind please paste your updated script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101527/discussion-between-suresh-reddy-guntaka-and-user310291).

Comment: I found why : it was </BODY> not </body>